# Stripe Webhook Data: Stringify/Parse not fixing 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1' issue in node JS. Leads to Converting Circular issue

Tags: node.js, json, stripe-payments

This seems to be a issue that has cropped up numerous times, but none of the solutions I've found have worked. When the data comes in from stripe, I get the 'unexpected token o' error, so I try to stringify and parse it, but I then get a different error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`. The console output is what is expected, but making it usable - even when following the exact code Stripe gives you as an example - fails. Below is my current code. Any idea how to fix this?

```
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), async (request, response) => {
    
  console.log(request.body);

  let event;

  try {
    event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      request.body,
      request.headers['stripe-signature'],
      endpointSecret
    );
    
    const customerSubscriptionUpdated = event.data.object;
    
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(400).send(`Stupid Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    return;
  }

  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.send();
});
```

Comment: Is there any other middlewares before your `app.post` that could have modify the behaviour of your `express.raw` middleware? For example, do you have some sort of `app.use(express.json())` before that line?

Comment: @AngYC I have the following `const app = express();`, `app.use(cors());`, `app.use(bodyParser.json());`, `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: Hi @CoreyRS, I have answered below which has proven my guess, please try the solution and see whether it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is very likely caused by having a JSON parser middleware in your `app` before your `/webhook` route is defined, something like this is in your code:

```js
app.use(express.json()); // or app.use(bodyParser.json()) in your case
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), (req, res) => {});
```

This caused the JSON data (identified with `Content-Type: application/json` header) to be parsed first before going into your route. However, `stripe` API specifically mention that this data has to be raw Buffer, thus it is invalid for the API.

The reason why I suggest so is because `JSON.parse({})` will resulting in the JavaScript trying to first cast the argument into a string (In this case `[object Object]`), JSON can understand the first character `[` (Opening bracket of an array) but starts to complain in the second character `o`, which results in the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

The solution is to move your middleware below your `.post('/webhook')`, which will cause it to only run for all routes declared after that:

```
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), (req, res) => {});
app.use(express.json()); // or app.use(bodyParser.json()) in your case
```

---

Alternatively, as suggested from the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/identity/handle-verification-outcomes#create-webhook), you can dynamically load the middleware as well:

```js
// Use JSON parser for all non-webhook routes
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
    next();
  } else {
    express.json()(req, res, next); // or bodyParser.json() in your case
  }
});
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), (req, res) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to @AngYC's answer above, the reason you must not parse request body json prior to signature verification (as applied when you add body-parser to your `app` with `app.use(bodyParser.json());`) is that Stripe's signature verification depends on the `raw body string` in the calculation. Parsing the JSON body causes that raw string to be unavailable and the signature comparison to fail to match.